# Create a variable as a reference for a long object in Go

Tags: go, optimization

I have a long object `update.PostType.RecievedFrom.Id` that I need to access many times inside my program,

but I want to shorten it, so it will be more readable, by creating a variable for it `id := update.PostType.RecievedFrom.Id`. now my question is would this variable be a "zero overhead" variable and will be just replaced as a macro in compile time, or it does affect my program (and if it is, how can I avoid it?)

Comment: Assuming from the variable names this is some sort of web app — a single requests allocates many orders of magnitude more memory than the one or two words taken by the extra variable, which probably does not even escape  the stack.

Comment: @JimB Indeed, I was just generally wondering if it affects the program. I guess I should've asked in a more suitable context than a web app request

Comment: So yes, it can alter the compiled code in some way, and no, it probably makes no measurable difference. The only sure way to know is inspect the machine code and benchmark any changes. Write code for readability first and foremost, and optimize when you encounter a problem you can measure.

Answer (score 5):

> will be just replaced as a macro in compile time [?]

No.

> or it does affect my program

Yes, but in a totally negligible way

> (and if it is, how can I avoid it?)

You cannot and you should not bother.

Comment: If so, should I declare id as `id := &...` or `id := ...`

Comment: @baronsec, if you need a pointer to the value, then use a pointer. We don’t know what the value is or what your requirements are.

Comment: @baronsec use `v := &x` when you need to modify `x` through `v` or when you need to "track" changes in `x` via `v`. Use `v := x` when all you need is to just capture the value of `x` at that point in time at which the statement is executed.